# Error al recibir update apk a través de FileProvider: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/cl.owl.pf.sdl/files/SDL 2.7

Tags: java, android, apk

Actualmente tengo configurada la aplicacion para recibir desde servidor una actualización a través de un apk, pero al momento de mostrar el download, esta se cae arrojando un mensaje de error.
Esta app la estoy ejecutando en un movil fisico con Android 10, comparto el codigo y los detalles:

**App_updater.java**

```
    File fileLocation = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), fileName);
    Intent intent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "cl.owl.pf.sdl.fileprovider", fileLocation);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent.setData(apkUri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileLocation),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    }
    mycontext.startActivity(intent);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
    android:authorities="cl.owl.pf.sdl.fileprovider"
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

**filepaths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_download" path="download"/>
</paths>
```

**EXCEPTION**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: cl.owl.pf.sdl, PID: 7534
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/cl.owl.pf.sdl/files/SDL 2.7
> at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:678)
> at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:377)
> at cl.sdl.pf.sdl.model.App_Updater.installApp(App_Updater.java:49)
> at cl.sdl.pf.sdl.model.App_Updater.access$000(App_Updater.java:20)
> at cl.sdl.pf.sdl.model.App_Updater$DownloadFile.onPostExecute(App_Updater.java:123)
> at cl.sdl.pf.sdl.model.App_Updater$DownloadFile.onPostExecute(App_Updater.java:60)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

Como referencia, la aplicación esta actualmente en la version 2.6 y el apk update que se necesita descargar e instalar al ejecutar la aplicación es la version 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente te sugiero que deberías migrar tu proyecto a AndroidX si estas usando una versión mayor a 4.0 de Android Studio.

En cuanto a tu problema, al definir la autoridad define el directorio `/files` :

```
// Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "cl.owl.pf.sdl.fileprovider", fileLocation);
 Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "cl.owl.pf.sdl.fileprovider/files/", fileLocation);
```

en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<provider
    android:authorities="cl.owl.pf.sdl.fileprovider/files/"
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

En tu archivo filepaths.xml *Muy importante para que evites una alerta de seguridad desde la consola el path debe terminar con "/" y definir un directorio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_download" path="download/"/>
    <external-path name="myfiles" path="files/"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!, Realice los cambios que mencionaste en tu respuesta, pero me volvio a salir la misma Excepcion: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/cl.owl.pf.sdl/files/SDL 2.7.